# Converting root to exponent

Tags: radicals

I am new to Math and learning Root, I came across two different Root and simply them. As Roots are the inverse operation of Exponents. I want to express the output in exponent for practice purposes. I am confused with the output of second question. Howe can I use output to express the exponent

√16 = 4 and I can write exponent as 4²

√12 = 2√3, How can I use the output to write an exponent expression of it?

Comment: It looks like your pattern is: If $\sqrt{a}=b,$ what power of $b$ will give back $a$? If that's it, then use the second power on $b$ so that $b^2=a.$ [This assumes $a,b \ge 0.$ ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sqrt[n]{x}$ can be rewritten as $x^{\frac{1}{n}}$.  So $\sqrt{12} = 12^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and 2$\sqrt{3}$ = 2 * $3^{\frac{1}{2}}$.